# How to characterize the accuracy of a tensor value determined experimentally?

Tags: tensor-calculus, measurements, error-analysis

How to characterize the accuracy of a tensor value determined experimentally? I'm particularly interested in first and second rank tensor values.

For a first-rank tensor (a vector), measurements are made to find the best estimate of the vector of the object being studied. There is the true vector $v_t$ of the object being measured and there is the experimentally measured vector $v_m$. The true and measured vectors can be described by their components, e.g., $<v_x, v_y, v_z>$, or perhaps by the magnitude of the vector $|v|$ and the components of its unit vector $u$ describing its orientation $<u_x, u_y, u_z>$.

The same can be said for a second-rank (symmetric) tensor $S_{ij}$. There is the true tensor $T_{ij}$ possessed by the object being measured and there is the experimentally measured tensor $M_{ij}$. The true and measured tensors can be described by their components, e.g.,

$$S_{ij}=\begin{bmatrix}S_{xx}&S_{xy}&S_{xz} \\\\
S_{yx}&S_{yy}&S_{yz} \\\\
S_{zx}&S_{zy}&S_{zz} \end{bmatrix}$$

, or perhaps by the magnitudes and directions of their three principal vectors (their eigenvalues and eigenvectors) $\lambda$ and $<l_x, l_y, l_z>$, respectively.

Comment: What's wrong with saying how uncertain each component is?

Comment: @ConnorBehan I suppose there is nothing wrong with that approach. Suppose for example, if two objects' vectors were measured, where the x,y,z component uncertainties for the first object were 1, 2, and 7 (units) and 3, 3, and 4 (units) for the second. Which measurement was more accurate?

Comment: This is ambiguous until "accuracy" is defined. In the case of a vector, for example, are we referring to the accuracy of one or more of the components, or the length, or the azimuth or another angle, or a weighted combination of these? We can expect even more possibilities for higher tensor ranks.

Comment: @Chemomechanics great comments. I would take accuracy $A$ to be how close a measured value $M$ is to the True value $T$. In equation form, $A = |M-T|$. In the vast majority of real measurements, we do not know this true value, but for this question I am assuming that we do. In my comment to Connor I mistakenly used the term uncertainty (measurement uncertainty), which is another topic. If I could re-state it: Suppose two objects' vectors were measured, where the x,y,z component accuracies for the first object were 1, 2, and 7 (units) and 3, 3, and 4 (units) for the second.....

Comment: @Chemomechanics ...Which measurement was more accurate? As you've pointed out, we are referring to the accuracy of all the components, and then the question is asked, "how do we define the combined accuracy of a multi-component measurement?" In essence this is what I am trying to ask. Perhaps there are several ways to go about it, but perhaps there is a preferred way within the scientific community?